# UIScrollView – Adjust User Scroll Amount Akin to Scrubbing?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have `UIScrollview` that the user scrolls up and down.

Is there a way to adjust how much the user's drag of the finger results in the final scroll amount?

I was looking at UIScrollview delegate methods, but haven't found a place to alter that.

`scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` seems too late since this is AFTER the event.

Comment: willBeginDragging and willEndDragging might be useful

Comment: We don't know what you mean by *"adjust how much the user's drag of the finger results in the final scroll amount"* ... do you want to scroll the content, say, 10-pts for every 1-pt of drag? Or scroll only 1-pt even if the user drags 100-pts? Or do you mean the deceleration *after* dragging is finished?

Comment: @DonMag I do not mean the deceleration rate. If the default is - 10 pixels dragged with the finger is 10 pixels of scrolling,  changing that rate to may be 10 pixels dragged with finger to 5 pixels of scrolling.

Comment: OK - I'm guessing your goal is not a typical scroll view.... otherwise your users will be frustrated and think there is something wrong with their device screens. A likely better route will be to use either a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `touches Began / Moved / Ended` and move your content by a scaled percentage of the motion.

Comment: No, I already have a typical scrollview, where the user scrolls up and down. I am trying to see if I an have a setting (fast/default/slow) which changes scrolling sensitivity.

Comment: @Gizmodo - do you have interactive content in your scroll view? Buttons, controls, text fields, etc?

Comment: @DonMag yes I do.

Answer (score 1):

iOS users are very familiar with using scrolling views, so changing the "scroll speed" may be confusing. However, it's your app :)

Give this a try...

When the user **Begins** dragging, we'll grab the `.contentOffset.y` as a "starting point." In `scrollViewDidScroll`, we'll get the difference between the *new* `.contentOffset.y` and the `startingY` ... multiply that by the speed factor ... and then change the `.contentOffset.y`.

Note that manually setting `.contentOffset.y` triggers `scrollViewDidScroll`, so we'll also need to set a bool flag to prevent recursion:

```
class SlowScrollVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    // scrollSpeed --- example values
    //  1.0 == normal
    //  1.5 == fast
    //  0.5 == slow
    var scrollSpeed: CGFloat = 0.5
    
    var startingOffsetY: CGFloat = 0
    var bManualOffset: Bool = false

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // add a bunch of labels and buttons so we have something to scroll
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 40
        
        for i in 1...20 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.backgroundColor = .cyan
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            let b = UIButton()
            b.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            b.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            stack.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // so we can see the scroll view frame
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])
        
        scrollView.delegate = self

        // you may also want to adjust .decelerationRate
        //  try various values to see the result
        //scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate(rawValue: 0.99)

    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        startingOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if !bManualOffset {
            // get the difference between previous offset.y and new offset.y
            let diff = scrollView.contentOffset.y - startingOffsetY
            // adjust by scroll-speed factor
            let newY = startingOffsetY + diff * scrollSpeed
            // prevent recursion
            bManualOffset = true
            // set adjusted offset.y
            scrollView.contentOffset.y = newY
            // update start Y
            startingOffsetY = newY
        }
        bManualOffset = false
    }
    
    @objc func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // just to confirm we tapped a button
        print("Tap:", sender.currentTitle)
    }

}
```